# Dynamically inserting strings into ACE code editor, angular JS

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, flask, code-editor

This is an app I am doing with angular JS, and flask as a backend.

I pretty much followed the ACE code editor tutorial exactly [as shown here](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding) and have that much of the code working. I now want to do something like this:

```
<div id= "editor">
    {{ '{{xml_string}}' }}
</div>
```

Where `xml_string` is grabbed from the backend via an `$http.get` call, and passed to the scope inside my controller like this. I am able to see the `xml_string` in its entirety when I do something like this:

```
<p> {{'{{xml_string}}'}} </p>
```

But for some reason, this is not displaying inside the code editor.

Now, the reason I have been using:

```
{{ '{{xml_string}}' }}
```

instead of:

```
{{xml_string}}
```

is because of a clash between angular's syntax and flask/jinja's syntax. I don't think that that is an issue. Anyone have advice on how to do something like this? I can post more code if necessary, but I hoped this is enough to describe the problem.

Comment: When are you instantiating the ACE editor?  On page load, or after response is returned from the server?

Comment: @SeanVieira, I believe on the page load. Technically I switched things up and now this is a directive, but the editor is there on the page load. I want to be able to click a button and have code populate the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the code into ACE as ACE most likely does not monitor the DOM for changes - instead, use [`editor.getSession().setValue(yourtext)`](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor) (`editor.setValue(yourText, -1)` would work as well, but it leaves entry in undo history)